# Using -XautoNameResolution in weblogic clientgen ant task

Tags: web-services, weblogic

I'm facing trouble generating artifacts for a wsdl which could be run using wsimport only after supplying -B-XautoNameResolution option.

I'm using weblogic specific ant tasks (jwsc, clientgen) to generate artifacts. As jwsc doesn't support wsimport in its body, how can I use -B-XautoNameResolution as a prameter in weblogic cliengen ant task ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced just now same problem, and solved it by switching to wsimport direct call instead of clientgen. You can find wsimport parameters used by clientgen into clientgen error message and add -B-XautoNameResolution.

Comment: But I cannot use wsimport inside 'module' ANT task of weblogic ?